# Python: function, passing argument

Tags: python, function, arguments, static-methods

I`m new to python and I have the stupid problem with passing an argument.

```
class MyClass():

    @staticmethod
    def add_group(name, parent_id):
        print "add_group method, name: %s, parent_id: %s" % (name, parent_id)
```

Other class method

```
def task():
    print "task method, name: %s, group_id: %s" % (name, parent_id)
    MyClass.add_group(name, parent_id)
```

Output:

```
task method, name: blabla, group_id: 15

add_group method, name: blabla, parent_id: (15L,)
```

What's happened with parent_id argument? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you passed in `group_id` not `parent_id`

Comment: You also called `MyClass.add`, and are showing us the definition of `MyClass.add_group`.

Comment: Where did `MyClass.add(name, group_id)` come from?

Comment: My next question would be - "Why do you want a @staticmethod"? Is it just for experimentation?

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken when i wrote, but problem still have

Comment: Please just copy/paste your code - none of this ties up

Comment: I have no idea where the problem is.

Comment: Class methods require a first argument `def task(cls, ...):`. Furthermore, the variables `name` and `parent_id` are not bound to anything in your `task` function. You have given us code which cannot possibly run.

Comment: All that is looks like is that you passed it two different types for `parent_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one case you passed in `15`, in the other case you passed in `(15L,)` (i.e. a tuple whose first value is 15L, that is long(15) or an arbitrary-precision number representing 15.)

Numbers naturally transform into longs when they become very large values such as 10**20, but in this case it is very small; the only way I can think of you would have gotten a long you weren't expecting was doing something like `10**20 - 10**20 + 15`, or somehow some other value in your program is a long.

*edit*: Specifically, the other value in your program may be being returned by a library you are using.

Comment: Thats the best answer I think the OP will ever get. Add an example of a @classmethod decorator and I call this golden.

Comment: Actually. the fact that the OP is getting a long makes me thing that its probably a direct returned value from a database driver. Normally you don't just randomly see a long unless you made one.